# Responsible of/for?

Tags: prepositions

I know that "responsible for" is common but I wonder what happens if I say, "Hitler is responsible of the massacre of Jews"?

I think that when one blames someone for something, using "of" makes sense.

My mother-language is not English but somehow "responsible of" makes more sense to me than the "responsible for".

Or I am just talking with no sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is "responsible for something" and "responsible to someone". How "responsible" is constructed in other languages is irrelevant.
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/responsible

Answer (score 0):

I think that usually

"*of*" - tends to be used as a possessive identifier as in "*son of Sam*" while "*for*" - can act as a helping verb (*for doing* this thing/that thing where the *doing* part is implied), as well as acting as a possessive identifier  as in "a gift *for* Sally" (maybe *possessive identifier* isn't exactly the right part of speech here but it does indicate a sort of possessiveness - Sally must be the owner of the gift if it is for her)